# Can't install vue + webpack template

Tags: webpack, vue.js

I'm using example from documentation https://vuejs-templates.github.io/webpack at Windows.

Very simple:

```
$ npm install -g vue-cli
$ vue init webpack my-project
$ cd my-project
$ npm install
$ npm run dev
```

And when i run `npm install` it fails with error:

```
1715 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/loose-envify 1ms (from cache)
1716 silly fetchPackageMetaData error for loose-envify@^1.0.0 Unexpected end of input at 1:1370
1716 silly fetchPackageMetaData s":{},"dist":{"shasum":"6b26248c42f6d4fa4b0d8542f78edfcde35642a8","ta
1716 silly fetchPackageMetaData                                                                      ^
1717 verbose stack SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input at 1:1370
1717 verbose stack s":{},"dist":{"shasum":"6b26248c42f6d4fa4b0d8542f78edfcde35642a8","ta
```

I'm very new to js. I understand that some packages can't load but I don't know what to do with this.

Comment: Try `npm cache clean --force`

Comment: @kichik it worked. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like npm has cached a bad response. Try [cleaning the cache](https://docs.npmjs.com/troubleshooting/try-clearing-the-npm-cache) with:

```
npm cache clean --force
```